# OpenTelemetry with Mesmer on Scala project: traces are not exported

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt, monitoring, open-telemetry

I'm trying to use OpenTelemetry on my Scala 2.13 project (microservices backend application with Play Framework, and Akka, ZIO and gRPC). I'm using [opentelemetry-java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/) with [Mesmer extension](https://mesmer.io/). I'm running the project with sbt just like in [Mesmer's Getting Started](https://mesmer.io/docs/getting-started/).

The problem is that I have no exported traces. I tried the `logging`, `zipkin` and `otlp`/`jaeger` exporter with debug log level but I got nothing.

Does anyone have experience with OpenTelemetry Java instrumentation ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You will need to add the exact "how's" of you use case here. There are hundred's of possible mistakes (or even variations) in "using OpenTelemetry on my Scala 2.13 project (microservices backend application with Play Framework, and Akka, ZIO and gRPC).". Easiest way will be creating the a hello-world-dummy-project with your exact pattern of usage and putting it on github.